# Optimising JQuery on scroll and stopping queuing of methods

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I am using the JQuery on scroll of which obviously runs as many times as the user scrolls however the animation lags if the user scrolls up and down fast enough. I'm assuming this is because every time a scroll is done the method is executed. I've done what I can to optimise the code below, if you have any ideas to improve it please let me know!

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var speed = 100;
    var triggerY = 50;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        count++;
        if (count>10) {
            var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
            if (currentY < triggerY) {
                if ($('#accountHolder').height() != 70) {
                    $('#barTitle').animate({fontSize: "40px"}, speed);
                    $('#barSlogan').fadeIn();
                    $('#accountHolder').animate({height: "70px"}, speed);
                    $('#accountPosition').animate({top: "13px"}, speed);
                }
             } else {
                if ($('#accountHolder').height() != 60) {
                    $('#barTitle').animate({fontSize: "32px"}, speed);
                    $('#barSlogan').fadeOut();
                    $('#accountHolder').animate({height: "50px"}, speed);
                    $('#accountPosition').animate({top: "5px"}, speed);
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`scroll` event is a very costly operation as it is fired everytime the user scrolls on the binded element.

If you are looking for performance, use CSS animations rather than JS animations. CSS animations are much faster and lag-free.

This is what I exactly mean.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var count = 0;
    var speed = 100;
    var triggerY = 50;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        count++;
        if (count>10) {
            var currentY = window.pageYOffset;
            if (currentY < triggerY) {
                if ($('#accountHolder').height() != 70) {
                    $('#barTitle').addClass('increase-font-size')
                    $('#barSlogan').addClass('show');
                    $('#accountHolder').addClass('increase-height');
                    $('#accountPosition').addClass('pull-down');
                }
             } else {
                if ($('#accountHolder').height() != 60) {
                    $('#barTitle').removeClass('increase-font-size')
                    $('#barSlogan').removeClass('show');
                    $('#accountHolder').removeClass('increase-height');
                    $('#accountPosition').removeClass('pull-down');
                }
            }
            count = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

These classes should have the animation styles.

```
.increase-font-size {
    font-size: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: font 2s;
    transition: font 2s;
}
.show {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    transition: opacity 2s;
}
.increase-height {
    height: 70px;
    -webkit-transition: height 2s;
    transition: height 2s;
}
.pull-down {
    top: 13px;
    -webkit-transition: top 2s;
    transition: top 2s;
}
```

Comment: Ill give it a go and let you know how it goes